# How to avoid redirecting to login form for some URL with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

This is the Spring Security configuration of my webapp

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", LOGIN, "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(CONFIGURATION).hasAuthority(Authorities.AUTHORITY_SOLMAN72_EXPORT_ENABLED.getKey())
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority(Authorities.AUTHORITY_SOLMAN72_EXPORT_ENABLED.getKey())
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage(LOGIN)
            .and()
        .addFilterBefore(oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Currently the server is redirecting to the `LOGIN` page every request that does not have the right credentials.

I want to redirect to the `LOGIN` page only the unauthorized requests to `CONFIGURATION`, while the unauthorized requests to `/api/**` should answer with 403.

What's a good way of achieving that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem using an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(LOGIN).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority(Authorities.AUTHORITY_SOLMAN72_EXPORT_ENABLED.getKey())
        .and()
    .addFilterBefore(oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthenticatedRequestHandler);
```

```java
@Bean
UnauthenticatedRequestHandler unauthenticatedRequestHandler() {
    return new UnauthenticatedRequestHandler();
}

static class UnauthenticatedRequestHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        if (request.getServletPath().startsWith("/api/")) {
            response.setStatus(403);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(LOGIN);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I went to implement dur's answer but noticed there's a [`ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html#defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor-org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint-org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher-) (available from around [Spring Security 3.2.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/)) which does effectively the same thing with much less dependent code:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"));
```

Moreover, I noticed specifying *any* `defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor()` [sets the first up as the default entry point](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.2.0.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.java#L252-L253).

By default, `FormLoginConfigurer`, `OAuth2LoginConfigurer`, `Saml2LoginConfigurer`, etc. [adds their own](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.2.0.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java#L257-L258) during `SecurityConfigurer.init()` and, unless we've specified one, the first among those becomes the default entry point.

This may or may not be useful, but because the 
 `AuthenticationEntryPoint` provided by `FormLoginConfigurer`, `OAuth2LoginConfigurer`, `Saml2LoginConfigurer`, etc. [avoids](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.2.0.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java#L268-L276]) requests containing the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, the entry point we've specified with `defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor()` will end up being used for AJAX, regardless of what we've specified for the request matcher argument.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.html):

> An `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which selects a concrete `AuthenticationEntryPoint` based on a `RequestMatcher` evaluation.

with [`Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint.html) for `/api/**` and [`LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) as default entry point.

```java
@Bean
public DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint() { 
    LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> entryPoints = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
    entryPoints.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"), new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
    DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint defaultEntryPoint = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(entryPoints);
    defaultEntryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(LOGIN));
    return defaultEntryPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As *@Michele Da Ros* answer did not work and *@antak*s uses methods that are deprecated and marked for removal, here is the same code with the new methods:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainAPI(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            ...

            // disable redirect to log in form and send 401 instead
            .exceptionHandling(ehc -> ehc
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                            (request, response, authException) -> {
                                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                            },
                            (request) -> request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api/")
                    )
            )

            ...
            .build();
}
```